# SQL Insert into with multiple subqueries

Tags: sql, ms-access, insert

I am able to get the following code to run in MS Access which is able to add a new row into the "NodeForce" table.

```
INSERT INTO [NodeForce] (nodeID, mem1, mem1min) 
SELECT '1113', '1752-1', [Row_ID] 
FROM [Element Forces - Frames] WHERE [FrameElem] = '1752-1' 
AND [OutputCase] = 'Case2' AND [ElemStation] = 0
```

However, when I add one additional subquery such as:

```
INSERT INTO [NodeForce] (nodeID, mem1, mem1min, mem1max) 
SELECT '1113', '1752-1', [Row_ID] 
FROM [Element Forces - Frames] WHERE [FrameElem] = '1752-1' 
AND [OutputCase] = 'Case2' AND [ElemStation] = 0,
[Row_ID] FROM [Element Forces - Frames] WHERE [FrameElem] = '1752-1' 
AND [OutputCase] = 'Case6' AND [ElemStation] = 12
```

it produces an error "Number of query values and destination fields are not the same."

How can I insert multiple values using different subqueries?

I also tried:

```
INSERT INTO ...
VALUES ('1113', '1752-1', (SELECT ... FROM ...), (SELECT ... FROM ...))
```

which then gave me an error saying "Query input must contain at least one table or query"

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: yes, the error is right, where is your second query ??? after the comma you have `[Row_ID] FROM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dissecting your query:

```
INSERT INTO [NodeForce] (nodeID, mem1, mem1min, mem1max) 
SELECT '1113', '1752-1', [Row_ID] 
FROM [Element Forces - Frames] WHERE [FrameElem] = '1752-1' 
AND [OutputCase] = 'Case2' AND [ElemStation] = 0
```

You are inserting 3 values to 4 columns thus the message `"Number of query values and destination fields are not the same."`

And the one below has no `SELECT` and is after the `SELECT` statement with three values
instead of after the `[Row_ID]` of the first `SELECT` statement.

```
,[Row_ID] FROM [Element Forces - Frames] WHERE [FrameElem] = '1752-1' 
AND [OutputCase] = 'Case6' AND [ElemStation] = 12
```

So, what you need to is to match the number of columns with your values and in that
case you need to make the second `SELECT` to be a subquery that is part of the first query
and would only return 1 value to be sure, like:

```
INSERT INTO [NodeForce] (nodeID, mem1, mem1min, mem1max) 
SELECT '1113', '1752-1', [Row_ID], (SELECT
[Row_ID] FROM [Element Forces - Frames] WHERE [FrameElem] = '1752-1' 
AND [OutputCase] = 'Case6' AND [ElemStation] = 12 LIMIT 1) 
FROM [Element Forces - Frames] WHERE [FrameElem] = '1752-1' 
AND [OutputCase] = 'Case2' AND [ElemStation] = 0
```

Where:

```
(SELECT
[Row_ID] FROM [Element Forces - Frames] WHERE [FrameElem] = '1752-1' 
AND [OutputCase] = 'Case6' AND [ElemStation] = 12 LIMIT 1)
```

is for `mem1max` which is a subquery that would return only 1 value and
is the 4th value to match your number of columns of 4 also.

Comment: Great, thank you! I knew I had 4 columns and 3 values, I just was not sure on how to properly add the 4th value.

Comment: @BryanT: Glad that it now work for you. Happy coding and GOD bless!